# Getting data from other elative pages after Login using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The following is the code that i have written and i am stuck after the login.
i want to scrape though the data of the user after login. How can i do that

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#login informations from Network requests
login_data={
    'honnan':'index.jsp',
    'login-azonosito':'******',
    'login-jelszo':'******',
    'login':'Login'
}

# creating sessions
with requests.Session() as s:
    url="Someurl here"
    r=s.get(url,verify=False)
    #print(r.content)
    soup =BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser') #parsing html contents
    login_data['honnan'] = soup.find('input',attrs={'name': 'honnan'})['value'] #getting the value of id in input field

    r=s.post(url,data=login_data) #passing login data
    print(r.content)

#scraping content
tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
    print(tag.get('href',None))
```

Comment: move the scraping inside `with` as with automatically close itself when you go out of it.

Answer (score 0):

you are making use of a `with` statement while using a session, all other scraping codes should go within the with statement because at the end of the with statement everything closes and exits. So take out the **with** statement or move all other beautiful soup code into it and you should be right as rain

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#login informations from Network requests
login_data={
    'honnan':'index.jsp',
    'login-azonosito':'******',
    'login-jelszo':'******',
    'login':'Login'
}

# creating sessions
with requests.Session() as s:
    url="Someurl here"
    r=s.get(url,verify=False)
    #print(r.content)
    soup =BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser') #parsing html contents
    login_data['honnan'] = soup.find('input',attrs={'name': 'honnan'})['value'] #getting the value of id in input field

    r=s.post(url,data=login_data) #passing login data
    print(r.content)

    #scraping content
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        print(tag.get('href',None))
```

hope this helped